# How to log in molecule?

Tags: python, ansible, molecule

I am using Molecule to test an Ansible role. I've written unit tests in python, and have been unable to print out variables or log anything to stdout. Here is my code

```
import os
import testinfra.utils.ansible_runner
import logging

LOG = logging.getLogger("toto")

testinfra_hosts = testinfra.utils.ansible_runner.AnsibleRunner(
    os.environ['MOLECULE_INVENTORY_FILE']).get_hosts('all')


def test_something(host):
    print 'Hello World!'
    LOG.warn('Hello World!')
    assert True
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enable the `s` flag for testinfra inside **molecule.yml**:

```
---
dependency:
  name: galaxy
driver:
  name: docker
lint:
  name: yamllint
platforms:
  - name: instance
    image: centos:7
provisioner:
  name: ansible
  lint:
    name: ansible-lint
scenario:
  name: default
verifier:
  name: testinfra
  lint:
    name: flake8
  options:
    s: true
```